# Left shift using %cl

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-shift

Let's say I have a number in binary. 1010 which is 10 in decimal.

I understand that shifting left by 1 bit is essentially multiplying the number by 2.

Theres a line in a textbook that's got me confused.

```
salq %cl, %rdx
```

`%rdx` is a number and `%salq` is a left shift. What I'm confused about is the `%cl`.

I've read that CL is 8 bits, does that mean I'm multiplying by 2^8?

Answer (score 4):

The `cl` partial register (which is really the lowest 8 bits of the register `rcx`) contains the value by which `rdx` will be shifted left. It's eight bits long, but the amount shifted is whatever is actually in there:

```
movb $10, %cl
salq %cl, %rdx ; rdx is shifted 10 bits left.
```

Answer (score 2):

CL is the shift count.  In C, it's `rdx <<= cl`, or `rdx = rdx << cl`.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html.

Or more precisely, `rdx <<= (cl&63)`, because x86 masks shift counts.

---

You're multiplying RDX by `2^cl`.

8 is the bit width of CL, meaning it can represent values from 0..255.